# Wordpress php sort query

Tags: wordpress, sorting

My question is how could i sort this entries i have, by `$count_fb`
it seems i cannot add a reference like this `$the_query = new WP_Query('orderby='.$count_fb.'&posts_per_page=6');`

weird that the script works and shows the links, but not in order to the highest `$count_fb` string
here's the code:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('orderby='.$count_fb.'&posts_per_page=6'); 

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$url = get_permalink($post->ID);
$fb_file = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($fb_file);
$count_fb = $json->$url->comments;

if ($count_fb == 0 || !isset($count_fb)) {
$count_fb = 0;
}

echo 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$url.$count_fb;
echo '<br />';

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: What is $count_fb supposed to be? Have you checked the orderby possibilities in the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters ?

Comment: well $count_fb is in while() getting the number of comments of every 6 wordpress posts. I am a beginner and i guess, i cannot use a a variable that within the while()

Comment: Do you have any code outside the loop to get the content for this variable `$count_fb` ? Because if you just have the one inside the loop it can't be applied to the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass your argument as an array instead of a string :

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ('orderby' => $count_fb, 'posts_per_page' => '6'));
```